# How to speak to a non-Muslim in order to invite them to Islam?

Tags: practical-islam, non-muslim, dawah

My question is maybe asked many times. I want to have some advices concerning how to speak about Islam (with a progressive way) to a non-Muslim friend, in order to invite this person to be a Muslim.

Things to know: the person is by nature a smart and really nice person, high education, and has many qualities (many qualities a good muslim should have). And this person is a Buddhist but not praticing (more atheist).

The person seems to be open minded enough to know about our religion.

I really want to speak by myself (not show her videos or something like this).

Comment: Quran speaks clearly - she should succumb without objections. But Quran also speaks other ways on other places, so who knows? Anyway, we are in a modern world, so it should go like: "Hi, want some islam?" "No, thanks." "Okay :)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing here is to understand her point of view already. I'll make some points you might want to focus on as a method of comparison with what she might be familiar with, as I'm an atheist so should have a good idea what she'll be receptive to.

1. To start, mention that Islam can be considered "purer" than probably any other religion. I recall that archaeologists recently found a very old version of the Qur'an, possibly from the Prophet's time, and it's much the same to what is now. No other religion has this, as they have been revised constantly over their history according to the needs of the current leaders, while Muslims have been consistently committed to keeping their scripture intact.
2. Mention that, unlike with most (possibly all?) other religions, Islam is more than just a belief, it's a way of life, and one which is open to all. It requires that you not only believe in Allah and Mohammad as his prophet, but pick up certain practices. Mention why those practices are done and what they give you.
3. Mention the dedication that Muslims have to their brothers and sisters and the good they do for each other.
4. Reiterate that the religion is truly open to all and Muslims will generally be happy to help welcome her.
5. Encourage her to do her own research! Islam is poorly understood in the West and she should look at neutral resources to teach her about it. Given how many negative misconceptions are out there it can only help your case.

Comment: Thank you @PointlessSpike , So according to the points you listed, the idea is not to go "deep" in religion, but to say how islam is pure and universal

Comment: I'd start by just mentioning how it differs in general from other religions. You can do deeper later, but there are fundamental differences that are important to understand first off. Beyond anything else, that's more likely to capture her interest than talking specifically about the Prophet's life and his teachings.

Comment: It seems 1. refers to the [Birmingham Quran manuscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birmingham_Quran_manuscript).  Fascinating.

Comment: Islam is understood at least a little, if not a lot, in the west (at least Europe, Americas, Australia) since many of its concepts are found in christianity or judeism (soul, judgement, omnipotence, quite a lot of prophets in common, similar rules and/or history, ...). A buddhist-atheist might have chosen buddhism precisely to espace all that.

Comment: @user5751924- All true. But it should be understood more because of the number of people who believe it and the increased exposure to it that the West is getting because of globalisation.

Answer (score 0):

**From Quran Verse:** An-Nahl 16:125

> Invite to the way of your Lord with wisdom and good instruction, and argue with them in a way that is best. Indeed, your Lord is most knowing of who has strayed from His way, and He is most knowing of who is [rightly] guided. [An-Nahl 16:125](https://qurano.com/en/16-an-nahl/verse-125/)

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. The right course has become clear from the wrong. So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.[Al-Baqara 2:2565](https://qurano.com/en/2-al-baqara/verse-256/)

Answer (score -1):

you have to describe all things and positivity about Islam especially tell him about Prophet Muhammad life like how he spent, what he wants what he thought and how he behaves. you must have to tell him that **Islam is a religion of peace**, find it [here](http://www.holypakistan.com/islam-is-a-religion-of-peace-justice-and-tolerance-not-terrorism/)

after analysing his/her body language you will know how he behaves about Islam so clear him/her that terrorism is not allowed in Islam. Islam is spreading with love